# Magento 2 di:compile command gives fatal error

Tags: magento2, slider, command-line, code-generation

I have taken reference of an old module (Bannerslider) created for Magento 2 Beta version and I am trying to convert it to Magento 2 stable compatible (Mycompany_Bannerslider).

When I enable the module and run the following command it doesn't give errors:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

But when I run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` command then it shows following error in the terminal:

[image]

Below is the model-collection file I am using:

```
namespace Mycompany\Bannerslider\Model\Resource\Banner;
class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->_init('Mycompany\Bannerslider\Model\Banner', 'Mycompany\Bannerslider\Model\Resource\Banner');
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you installed magento 2 release 17/11 ?

Comment: Yes the 2.0.0 stable version.

Comment: You need refactor your module, it can work fine with this version

Comment: Please explain what should I do in detail for "refactoring", I recompiled but this error is persistent.

Answer (score 3):

Change **Resource** to **ResourceModel**

```
namespace Mycompany\Bannerslider\Model\ResourceModel\Banner;
class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->_init('Mycompany\Bannerslider\Model\Banner', 'Mycompany\Bannerslider\Model\ResourceModel\Banner');
        }
}
```

Comment: Did that but still same error, please explain what could be the issue, changed implementing class path still same error.

Comment: In magento2 there are no Resource concept. So use ResourceModel instead Resource. That means Resource folder should replace with ResourceModel and change namespace to. Clear?

Comment: Here is an example of using resource model https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-sample-module/tree/master/SR/Weblog/Model

Comment: Thanks, your hint fixed my plugin. Following this clue, I found this answer really helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31984198/1903781

Answer (score 2):

You need refactor your module from Magento2 `1.0.0` to Magento2 `2.0.0`. It included many change, i can list something in the following:

1. You find and replace all namespace have contain `Resource` to `ResourceModel`
2. Change name `Resource` folder to `ResourceModel` in `Yourcompany/YourModule/Model`
3. Change all format(`xsd`) of `.xml` file in `etc` folder.
4. Change Observer/Event(if it exist include: `events.xml` and path).

...